# How to install Opera web browser system level (for all users) using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Using powershell commands I am trying to install Opera browser on my system which is having multiple user accounts.

I tried the below method.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Test\Opera.exe" -ArgumentList '/install /silent /launchopera=0 /setdefaultbrowser=0 /allusers=1' -Passthru
```

But this is installing only for the current user. is there a way i can install for all users

any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the issue is with the `-ArgumentList` parameter. Instead of a single string, it is expecting an array of strings. This means that you have to break up the arguments into separate strings. Second, you may have to run as administrator with the `RunAs` command:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Test\Opera.exe" -ArgumentList '/install', '/silent', '/launchopera=0', '/setdefaultbrowser=0', '/allusers=1' -Passthru -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scriptblock and invoke command:

```
$Install = { path\file.exe /s /v/qn }

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Install
```

resource : [Microsoft Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Please explain how you are solving the problem, in addition to providing scriptblock